# perf_event_mmap_page has no member named data_size

Tags: linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf

I'm working with [perf_event_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) and I have mapped the meta data page to virtual memory according to this command:

`struct perf_event_mmap_page *meta_page = mmap(NULL, sizeof(stuct perf_event_mmap_page), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);`

but for some reason and upon compiling, I got an error that perf_event_mmap_page has no member named data_size. I have checked `perf_event.h` and the data structure is defined with the members according to the documentation. what is the reason behind this error?

Comment: What kernel version are you using? Which `perf_event.h` did you check? Also please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Zulan Although kernel version is 4.12, `perf_event.h` for the kernel installed on my system doesn't not contain `data_size` and `data_offset` as members for `struct perf_event_mmap_page`!

Comment: Well, then your distribution is giving you the wrong `perf_event.h`. The [stock 4.12](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L419) does contain them. That may be because it is part of a different package (e.g. linux-libc-dev) than the kernel itself and they aren't on the same version.